# CASE WHEN SQL - Timelogs Crediting

Tags: mysql, case

I am trying to code a statement where when an employee swipe his/her id on a night-shift schedule, the hours credited for that day will fall on the date-out. Can you give me some insights through this? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide tables, sample data and expected output. Preferably also what you have tried yourself so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you as for case calusule it is pretty simple:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SurName
    ID,
    CASE
        WHEN (ID IN (1, 3, 5) AND
            (NAME IS NOT NULL) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS ValidUser,
FROM db.UserTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Empname where swipe=1 and shift=b;

swipe:
1 = swipe
0= not swipe

shift:
a= morning
b= night